# Using withErrors([])

Tags: laravel-8

I am trying to use `withErrors([])` like below.

```
return Redirect::back()->withErrors(
                [
                    'login' => 'Login is not successful.'
                ]
            );
```

I am getting output like below

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => "Login is not successful."
]
```

Is it possible to get a `key` in array while using `withErrors([])` ?

Comment: Can you show the full method ?

Answer (score 0):

you can simply get all the errors values in session. just try out like the below answer.

{{session('errors')->first('login')}}